# how to disable pagination programmatically in Drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal, pagination, drupal-8

i need to disable the pagination for the view also the items per page.

i have tried this code below but nothing happend, no erros,nothing being changed.
[image]

```
   $view = Views::getView($view->id());
   $view->setDisplay('default');
   $pager = $view->display_handler->getOption('pager');
   $pager['type'] = 'none';
   $view->display_handler->setOption('pager', $pager);
   $view->display_handler->options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
```

the pagination should not be shown.

Comment: i managed to remove the pagination with $view->setItemsPerPage(0);
but still have that "items per page"

Comment: Why you have to do it from code? Why don't you just make another display and select no pagination for it?

Comment: it's for a specific content type